# How do I loop over this nested array in Vue wth v-for?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js, v-for

I am aiming to create a navigation menu, where each `div` will have a header and a list of links

```html
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add the link data to the `data()` in Vue, and I have attempted it like so:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                links: {
                    columns: [
                        {
                            heading: 'Feature',
                            attr: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Something'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the HTML with the attempt to use `v-for`

```html
<template>
    <div class="pt-8 sm:pt-16 h-screen navigation-background-gradient">
        <nav class="mx-4 sm:mx-48">
            <div class="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-56">
                <div v-for="link in links.columns">
                    <h1 class="mb-5 text-white font-semibold font-montserrat tracking-wider uppercase text-2xl text-shadow-glow">{{ link.heading }}</h1>
                    <ul class="space-y-4">
                        <li>
                            <a class="block text-lg text-menu-link font-inter font-medium tracking-wider" href="#">{{ link.attr }}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>
```

So I can access the `heading` fine, but I can't access `attr.text`

If I echo out `attr.text` I get `[ { "text": "Something" } ]` but I aren't sure how to get to it. I thought I may need to do another loop, as it's an array, but I couldn't work out the correct combination to use to make it show.

I feel like I am close and missing something obvious, but I can't see it.
Can anyone suggest me where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

@Chris, attr is an array so you have to access this by index. So for your case, you can do like

```
{{ link.attr[0].text }}
```

As your code shows attr array contains only one item so I have done `attr[0]` as to get first item of an array we use 0 index.

And If your `attr` array contains more than one element then you have to loop through another loop as used in below link 

[Nested loop in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029856/nested-loop-in-vue)

Comment: I intend on having more than one item, what's the best way to get the index?

Comment: you have to add another loop @ChrisMellor

Comment: That's the bit I seem to be struggling with, do you have any examples of using a second loop for that array? @Dcoder

Comment: plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029856/nested-loop-in-vue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dcoder, who pointed me in the right direction, I was able to work it out. I will post here in case others come across this - hopefully it might be helpful!

I had to do another loop on the `<li>` but using the array from the first loop (`links.columns`), so my second loop consists of:

```html
<li v-for="attribute in link.attr">
  <a href="#">{{ attribute.text }}</a>
</li>
```

As you can see, `link` stores the rest of the array data, and as `attr` is also an array, I can loop through that.